GPS snooze on Android 12
What has been discovered is that if Android is left with GPS location listener running indoors where there is no coverage for several hours, then GPS enters a snooze mode: snooze we loose

The GPS receiver is dead as a rat, no matter what app is used to try to compel a location
every 25 to 65 minutes, GPS wakes up for around 3 minutes, and if a satisfactory fix isn’t obtained, it re-enter snooze
We know that downloading the GPS catalog takes 12.5 minutes, and a cold first fix could take 25 minutes, so the GPS receiver can effectively snooze forever if the sky isn’t clear for one of those 2-minute time to first fix
time to first fix from snooze is on average 10 minutes plus the actual time to first fix
No update AGPS settings or being online fixes anything
The user would expect the GPS tirelessly retrying, since a cold fix can be obtained in 12.5 minutes or so. This is not what GPS is doing
powering off the phone and unplugging the power cable does not fix

The phones are Android 12 era Pixels
Can Android GPS somehow be forced to seek a fix continuously for 25 minutes?
Does a trick exist to get out of snooze-jail?
.
This pertains to Google Pixel phones which have gps enclave by either:

Qualcomm Snapdragon
Broadcomm

.
The gps enclave is hardware, software and data, including AGPS data:

Android provides very limited control and inspection of gps operations
What has been discovered here is that a battery-preserving feature snoozing the gps causes:
the first-fix after an extended period of operating out of coverage delayed an average of 10 minutes and
possibly indefinitely for poor receiver conditions where
a fix would be possible were there a continuously operating gps receiver

.
What is missing from Android is compromise-less gps operations were obtaining more gps fixes is prioritized over battery life
.
Discovered with Broadcomm:

AGPS data can apparently not be controlled from Android
time cannot be injected either, frequently Broadcomm produces fix times timestamped in 2005. Reboot is only fix for fix times
Never lists all satellites like 30 or so
reports higher signal strengths than Snapdragon, but is worse at getting fixes


When I worked with location services and GPS data tracking in Android, it only took mere seconds to get an initial fix on the location, and the app never seemed to lose GPS signal during usage and testing. Can you refer me to the documentation you found this info in?

The key is to leave gps running where there is no coverage for several hours, like overnight inside your home. I did extensive morning testing to determine exactly how the GPS provider returned to being responsive. Another observed issue is that after starting in a poor coverage area, fix quality deteriorates minute by minute until there is no fix to be had, even if AGPS reload is attempted. Recovery could take an hour

I think you need to provide a LOT more proof that this is real.  I've had plenty of devices not have GPS for hours or days and then get a first fix within seconds.  Either something else is happening completely different, or your device is broken.

What this does sound kind of like is an ancient device of mine which would have lots of problems getting a first fix.  Turns out a screw was loose, and that screw was either part of or adjacent to and interfering with the GPS antenna.  Tightening it fixed the phone.  I'd check for physical issues with your device before blaming Android or even a bad OEM build here.

I want comments from those who have insights, not random criticism. The GPS is an enclave, and different manufacturers’ chip have nothing in common. This is the behavior of every tested generation of Pixel, which might be Qualcomm chip. This is original research: for 15 years, no one have pinpointed this problem among all other reasons for not getting a fix. It took 3 test implementations and patience

I believe it a legacy design decision to preserve battery that prevents alternative use driven by other priorities. On Android, users have very limited control over gps

The impact is for a 24/7 logger, if leaving a non-coverage location after long time, the first 10 minutes worth of fixes is are lost. All other built-in location on Android since 10 or so uploads absolutely everything to Google that 2024 is being sued by the DoJ. Other providers are also disabled if Google’s gms-something cannot upload to Google
